# How do I write those cool command line code generators (rails, sproutcore, webgen)

Tags: ruby

I've grokked the code for all the aforementioned apps and I still can't find a straightforward way to create a static directory structure from a single command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [rubigen](http://rubigen.rubyforge.org).  You can also view a [presentation](http://rubyconf2007.confreaks.com/d3t1p1_rubigen.html) by dr nic.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to able to issue a command that will generate an entire directory tree?

```
cp -r <template> <destination>
```

Or am I misunderstanding?  If you want to generate a consistent directory structure, your best bet is to simply copy it from a template.  Fast, easy, done.